# Editing user groups using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to add multiple members to local admin group, below is the code

```
function Add-Admin {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param
([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,HelpMessage="UserName to be added to local Admin Group")]
[string[]]
$username
,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,HelpMessage="Domain in which the UserName exists")]
[string[]]
$domain
)
$strComputer="localHost"
$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
$computer.name
$Group = $computer.psbase.children.find("administrators")
$Group.Add("WinNT://" + $domain + "/" + $username)
$Group.name
$Group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
}
```

when I run the function im able to run it as

Add-Admin -username vinith -domain corp.a.org

what i want is, to supply multiple user names to be added

Add-Admin -username vinith,ith,itops -domain corp.a.org

can anyone help me out on how to go about & add **vinith,ith,itops** (more than one user at a time)

Comment: Please edit your title to something relevant to your question.

Comment: Please modify the title of your question as currently it does not relate to the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider your $username variable as an array (as it is)

replace :

```
$Group.Add("WinNT://" + $domain + "/" + $username)
```

by

```
foreach ($user in $username)
{
  $Group.Add("WinNT://" + $domain + "/" + $user)
}
```